# React imports outside of src/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I was following this guy video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPQ1-33teR4, and when I try to import it shows the following error:

> ./src/App.js
>   Module not found: You attempted to import /components/Default which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code as well? Showing the import line?